# Pass Parameter to GCMLE Prediction Graph

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

Ror my ML Engine Prediction Graph, I have a part of the graph which takes a long time to compute and is not always necessary. Is there a way to create a boolean flag that will skip over this section of the graph? I would like to pass this flag when creation a batch predict job or an online prediction. For example, it would be something like:

`gcloud ml-engine predict --model $MODEL --version $VERSION --json-instance $JSON_INSTANCES --boolean_flag $BOOLEAN_FLAG`

In the example above, I would either pass True/False as the `$BOOLEAN_FLAG` and then this would determine whether a part of the prediction graph is evaluated. I would imagine that this flag could also be passed in the body of the batch prediction job, just like model/version are. Is this at all possible?

I know that I could add a new input field to the prediction request that is True/False for each element in the batch and just pass that as False when I don't want to obtain the prediction, but I'm curious if there is a way to do this with just a single parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible. We'd like to hear more about your requirements for this feature. Please reach out to us at cloudml-feedback@google.com

Answer (score 0):

How about adding two different export signatures, each with a different head? Then you can deploy to two different endpoints? Choose the url to call depending on whether you want full or partial.

Write two serving input functions, one for each case. In the first case, set the flag to zero, and in the second case, set the flag to one.  The reason to use ones_like and zeros_like is to ensure that you have a batch of zeros and ones:

```
def case1_serving_input_fn():
    feature_placeholders = ...
    features = ...
    features['myflag'] = tf.zeros_like(features['other'])
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, feature_placeholders)

def case2_serving_input_fn():
    feature_placeholders = ...
    features = ...
    features['myflag'] = tf.ones_like(features['other'])
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, feature_placeholders)
```

In your train_and_evaluate function, have two exporters:

```
def train_and_evaluate(output_dir, nsteps):
  ...
  exporter1 = tf.estimator.LatestExporter('case1', case1_serving_input_fn)
  exporter2 = tf.estimator.LatestExporter('case2', case2_serving_input_fn)
  eval_spec=tf.estimator.EvalSpec(
                       input_fn = make_input_fn(eval_df, 1),
                       exporters = [exporter1, exporter2] )
  tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

Comment: this sounds promising! Can you point me to an example with two different export signatures? I know that within my tf.estimator.FinalExporter I can pass different serving functions, but it's not clear how I could have two different export signatures with different graphs beyond the serving function?